# Передача данных из завершившегося потока в работающий

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Мы запускаем параллельно 2 потока, они выполняют какую-то длительную работу. Мы знаем, что потом А выполнится быстрее потока B. Как после завершения А передать его результат потоку B?

Приходит в голову решение в лоб: писать результаты работы первого потока в статическую переменную и читать ее во втором потоке. Но мне кажется есть способы получше. Может вы знаете, как это сделать?

Comment: Статика это перебор. Писать лучше не в статическую переменную, а в общий для обоих потоков экземпляр. Создайте класс с переменной и вручите экземпляр класса обоим потокам.

Comment: @vitidev а почему экземпляр лучше статики?

Comment: Потому что виден только нужным потокам и не нужно чистить после окончания потоков. Статика только для **вечно** живущих вещей

Comment: Вы привели пример задачи, но есть, наверное, и реальное её применение. Скорее всего у вас это не просто переменная, а коллекция каких то данных вычисляемых в одном из параллельных потоков, так вот для именно параллельного выполнения массы потоков есть такие инструменты как Parallel.ForEach, а для хранения результатов таких вычислений - ConcurrentBag (https://habrahabr.ru/post/241706/). Пока что вы рассматриваете простую задачу, но в итоге придётся иметь дело с бОлее массивными вычислениями. Изучайте, пробуйте, совершенствуйтесь! =)

Answer (score 7):

Правильный вариант — вовсе не работать с низкоуровневой абстракцией потока. Для возвращения значений у вас есть `Task<T>`, его и используйте.

Например:

```
Task<int> Compute()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int result;
            // длинные сложные вычисления
            return result;
        };
}
```

Теперь этим результатом можно пользоваться:

```
Task<int> computeTask = Compute();

// проверить, завершились ли вычисления
if (computeTask.IsCompleted) // ...

// дождаться окончания работы и получить результат
int result = await computeTask;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string s = "";
       Task<int> A = new Task<int>(() =>
       {
           Thread.Sleep(500);
           //.....
           s = s + "Return 77 from A\n";
           return 77;
       });

        Task B= new Task(async () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //.....
            var x = await A;
            s = s + string.Format("B got {0} from A",x);
        });
        A.Start();
        B.Start();
        B.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```